# max width issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

can someone help me resolving this issue I am facing in IE8. Below is my html code -

try this in any browser then try same in IE8

jsfiddle.net/G2C33/

Output should appear like this
[image: this is how it suppose to work]

you can see that max width property will not work in IE8.

Note : Try this in IE8 or IE9(IE8 standard mode). If you try this after IE9 version then this will work as rendering engine is been changed after that. JS Fiddle will force to run document in IE9 Standard mode. So copy this into .html file and try.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
<style>
.first {
    width: auto !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.test{
    width : auto;
    max-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.second {
}

td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><ul>
            <li class="first"><div class="test">a very long content goes over</div></li>
            <li class="first"><div class="test">a very long content goes over here in this table cell and column a very long content goes over here in this table cell and column</div></li>
        </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="second"> 
            a very long content goes over here in this table cell and column a very long content goes over here in this table cell and column
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this one

Comment: Not just max width but white-space: nowrap; will also not working in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does support the max-width attribute but only when given a defined width first. So instead of `width:auto` assign some width for your class. It will work.

For example:

```
.test{
width: 100%;
max-width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```